# Affect one window with another in PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a Main window that has a settings window that pops out. I want to be able to change one of the settings and it affects the Main window

So far I have

mainwindow.py (the function I want to run to make a frame visible)

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.button_open_settings.clicked.connect
                                             (self.open_settings)
    
    def open_settings(self):
        self.settings_window = settings.MainWindow_settings(self)
        self.settings_window.show()

    def set_toggle_vis(self, toggle):
        self.ui.frame_toggle_list.setVisible(toggle)
```

settings window.py

```
class MainWindow_settings(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow_settings, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.ui = settings_ui.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def change_toggle(self):

        toggle_enabled = 1
  
        from mainwindow import MainWindow

        MWind = MainWindow()
        MWind.set_toggle_vis(toggle_enabled)
```

This kinda works, but it doesn't set the visibility of the frame to 1 as it would if I ran it from the mainwindow, it created a whole new main window, so now 2 are open.

How do I get it to refresh the mainwindow rather than opening a new one?

Comment: Assuming that the setting window is a QWidget subclass, create a custom signal for it and emit it whenever necessary, then in the main window connect that signal with `set_toggle_vis`.

Comment: It's not a QWidget subclass, it's a QMainWidget in its own .py file. I've been making all the windows you open as QMainWindows because I didn't know any better. I'm guessing making them a QWidget would be better. How do I make the mainwindow the settings windows parent from another .py file? I have updated the post to show the setup a bit better.

Comment: What I meant is that you did subclass from a QWidget type (Note: QMainWindow inherits from QWidget). In any case you certainly should **not** create a new instance. As said above, create a custom signal for `MainWindow_settings` and then in `open_settings` connect that signal to `set_toggle_vis`; finally, emit that signal in `change_toggle`. Please do some research in custom signals, as there are *a lot* of resources on the subject, starting from the documentation of both [Qt](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and [PyQt](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).

Comment: I used pyqtSignal and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question (with the help of musicamante)

Instead of calling the function I use pyqtSignals to send a signal

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.button_open_settings.clicked.connect
                                             (self.open_settings)
    
    def open_settings(self):
        self.settings_window = settings.MainWindow_settings(self)
        self.settings_window.toggle_submitter.connect(self.set_toggle_vis)
        self.settings_window.show()

    def set_toggle_vis(self, toggle):
        self.ui.frame_toggle_list.setVisible(toggle)
```

settings window.py

```
class MainWindow_settings(QMainWindow):
    toggle_submitter = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow_settings, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.ui = settings_ui.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def change_toggle(self)
        toggle_enabled = 1
        self.toggle_submitter.emit(toggle_enabled)
```